# How to warmup application inside Docker Container?

Tags: docker

We have a docker application that when it is deployed has to do a warmup, else the first request will be really slow.

It is a shell script that just caches the routes and classes.

We are using the same dockerfile for development and would like to keep doing that.

How can we do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would override the entrypoint with a custom script which runs your original entry point command and then warm-up shell script.

You would have to make sure the last command is long running to keep the container running. You could use [Supervisor](https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/) for this purpose.